# My iOS app crashes on start up

Tags: ios, logging, crash

I have been developing an iOS app perfectly normally and then all of a sudden when I start the debugger I get a bunch of machine code and it halts here:

```
0x2c70bb:  popl   %ebp
0x2c670bc:  ret
```

I get no output in the log.  When I run zombies or leaks the app runs fine, but when I just use the simulator I get nothing.  I even put my breakpointer in the first line of code in the app delegate and it doesn't hit it.

Any tips?  I even went back in my code to the previously working code before this happened and it does the same thing.  Ive been developing iOS about 2 years and this is a first.

I have searched for a solution but have found nothing.

Comment: How did you revert back? Source control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this is the strangest thing.  I figured out the issue, but still not sure exactly why this happens.

I have a singleton class I use to store some run time settings info..
I have a class with specific settings that I assign to the main singleton class.

Inside the specific settings class, I have about 15 properties.  The crash happens if I add any more properties than 15.  If I add a 16th property to the class, the app crashes on startup, it never even reaches the code in main.m.

This is very strange and I have no way to explain it.  I can only assume it is a memory issue, but seriously, it only has 15 properties.

1 int
12 NSStrings
2 NSMUtableArrays that have only a few records each

If anyone has an idea of why this happens, please let us know...

Answer (score 0):

If your app delegate is not hitting then it will be crashing within the autorelease pool statement in your main.m.

Without a full stack trace it's difficult to debug.  I'd recommend the following:

- make sure your main window and root xibs are all ok
- stripping everything but the basics from your app delegate

Also, inside your main.m file, you should see something similar to this:

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

The fourth argument is the delegateClassName, and [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) says:

> delegateClassName
>       The name of the class from which the application delegate is instantiated. If principalClassName designates a subclass of UIApplication, you may designate the subclass as the delegate; the subclass instance receives the application-delegate messages. Specify nil if you load the delegate object from your application’s main nib file.

So I would double check that your delegate class name is being set either in the applications main xib, or in your delegate - I'd suggest being explicit and adding it if it isn't already there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on your main to **catch exception** (Supporting Files : main.m):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int retVal = 0;
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *classString = NSStringFromClass([CDAppDelegate class]);
        @try {
            retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, classString);
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception - %@",[exception description]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Or/And you can try to see if you have a **snapshot to restore**. (But the best practice is to have a **git repot** and commit/push regularly ;) )

Comment: I tried this and even put a breakpointer on the int retVal = 0; and it does not hit the breakpoint and it does the same crash.

Comment: Don't you have stack trace in Debug session ?